# NHibernate collection Count() dilemma

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I usually use a "Page -> Service -> Repository" pattern in my applications putting all my database calls in "repository" classes.

In some situations I've to test collection items count in my service logic.

Example:

```
EventService eventService=container.Resolve<EventService>();
IEnumerable<Event> events=eventService.GetAll();
if(events.Count()>0)
{
    ...do something...
}
```

Using NHibernate this will generate automatically a SQL statement with a DB access out of my repository class.

Can I avoid this? Is there a best practice?

Comment: Are you wanting to count database persisted objects without going to the database?  I am having a little difficulty understanding your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to avoid exposing `IQueryable<T>` on repositories for the following reasons:

- Many of the methods or not supported and it is not always clear what kind of query will be generated.
- Supporting ad hoc queries undermines the importance of designing proper indexes for specific uses cases.
- You lose the specification of the kind of queries that are expected.

Instead I would opt for using a simple query object which is translated into whatever it needs to be by the repository.

For this case in particular I would have a method on the repository returning a paginated list of events:

```
IList<Event> GetAll(int startIndex, int count);
```

This also highlights the importance of pagination. In the repository this would like something like:

```
this.Session.Linq<Event>().Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
```

You may also choose to create a wrapping object for IList which can contain the total count as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are (unit) testing your service layer then you should be mocking your repositories. You can create a mock repository with a static list of objects exposed as an IQueryable.

This way when you call Count() it will return a count of your static list, something that you can reliably assert.

Update

My mistake, I assumed from this line

> I've to test collection items count in
>   my service logic

That you wanted to test this logic of  your service.

Your above code looks like you are returning an IQueryable. So as soon as you call `Count()` or `ToList()` (essentially anything that enumerates the IQueryable) you will hit the database.

So either change your service to return `IList<T>` or change your code to the below:

```
EventService eventService=container.Resolve<EventService>(); 
IEnumerable<Event> events = eventService.GetAll().ToList(); 
if(events.Count()>0) {     ...do something... }
```

You will hit the database when you call `ToList()`, but not when you call `Count()` as you are working with an in-memory collection.

Comment: No! This is not unit testing code. This is a Service class example.